# Get row values of CSV file having particular value using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

[image: csvfile]

I have multiple
I want to get rows of Name.
I know how to get by index using [dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-the-specified-row-value-of-a-given-pandas-dataframe/) but I want to get using row name as index might change.
like

```
(row=="Name" ) or (row== "name")
```

output be like :

[image: output]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name column `name = df['Name']`